raycast not being detected only on rapier trimesh collider?
I have a jump function on a capsule collider that works on hull colliders but not trimesh colliders. I have a log that is false when in the air and true when on the ground when over a hull collider, but when im over trimesh it says null, why would that be?
 const ray = world.castRay(
      new RAPIER.Ray(ref.current.translation(), { x: 0, y: -1, z: 0 })
    );

    const grounded = ray && ray.collider && Math.abs(ray.toi) <= 1.75;
    console.log("grounded", grounded);

    if (jump && grounded) ref.current.setLinvel({ x: 0, y: 7.5, z: 0 });
  });

  return (
    <>
      <RigidBody
        ref={ref}
        colliders={false}
        mass={1}
        type="dynamic"
        position={[0, 10, 0]}
        enabledRotations={[false, false, false]}
        onSleep={false}
      >
        <CapsuleCollider args={[0.75, 0.5]} />
      </RigidBody>
    </>
  );
}

 return (
    <>
      <RigidBody
        type="fixed"
        colliders="trimesh"
        restitution={0.2}
        friction={1}
        position={[0, 1.25, 0]}
      >
        <primitive
          object={envi.scene}
          position-y={planePosition}
          scale={planeScale}
        />
      </RigidBody>
    </>
  );
}

